# MongoDB unique index with missing/null field

Tags: mongodb

How can I define a unique index that achieves the following goal:

If `name` field is missing (or null), allow only one document with the same `id`, but if the `name` exists, allow multiple instances of it as long as `(id,name)` is unique.

Good

```
{
    "id" : "a",
    "name" : "John"
},
{
    "id" : "a",
    "name" : "Hugo"
}
```

Good

```
{
    "id" : "a"
}
```

Bad

```
{
    "id" : "a",
    "name" : "John"
},
{
    "id" : "a",
    "name" : "John"
}
```

Bad

```
{
    "id" : "a",
}
{
    "id" : "a",
    "name" : "John"
}
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#partial-index-with-unique-constraint

Comment: @AlexBlex Can you demonstrate? I was unsuccessfully trying to figure out how to use partial indexes to solve this.

Comment: I think one additional scenario must be considered...  BAD  { "id": "a" }, { "id": "a" }, or is this condition OK?

Comment: @barrypicker this scenario is bad

Answer (score 0):

Conditional indexes can be implemented with [Partial indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#partial-index-with-unique-constraint).

If I get the requirement it's just these 2 indexes:

```
  {
    "name": "id_idx",
    "key": {
      "id": 1
    },
    "partialFilterExpression": {
      "name": null
    },
    "unique": true
  },
  {
    "name": "id_name_idx",
    "key": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": 1
    },
    "partialFilterExpression": {
      "name": {
        "$gt": ""
      }
    },
    "unique": true
  }
```

Comment: `db.name.insertOne({ id: "a", name: "John" }) db.name.insertOne({ id: "a" })`           the second insert should fail but it doesn't.

Comment: Could you elaborate why? I must be missing something

Comment: This is how I created the indexes: https://gist.github.com/galbarm/197870fb3955aa48eea559a61b26ff38

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, why the `{ id: "a" }` insert should fail?

Comment: Because the requirement is that if there is a document with id "x", that has no name field, then this should be the only document with id "x" in the collection. See the last example in the original question.

Comment: hmm, then it's just single regular unique `{"id": 1, "name": 1}`. No conditions. Or do I miss something again?

Comment: If you use this regular unique index, you can still have both `{ id: "a", name: "John" }` & `{ id: "a" }` as documents in the collection but it should be forbidden. Only one is allowed.

Comment: I think I get it. Essentially the empty "name" should match any string in uniqueness calculation, yes? I doubt it's possible.